# How to draw things on top of objects drawn in OnRenderObject()?

Tags: c#, rendering, unity

I am using Unity, [here is the method in question](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderObject.html). So I know this method draws objects after the camera is done rendering the scene. I have not come across a way in Unity to draw these objects in a certain layer, rather than being the last thing to be drawn.

If it all possible, I am looking to do exactly that: have my custom shaped objects not be renderered last. The problem is that it draws over the UI as well as one other thing that it shouldn't draw over (the player). In case anybody ask I have to use custom UI because the game uses Kinect; basically sprites that detect when the player's hand is over them.

Here is a picture of part of my scene and the problem at hand:

[image]

In this example the custom object is a simple line (I cannot use Unity's line renderer for separate reasons).